# Prove $\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+n)<\sin(\frac{1}{2})+\sin(\frac{1}{4})+\sin(\frac{1}{6})+ ...+\sin(\frac{1}{2n})<\frac{1}{2}\ln(n)+\ln(2)?$

Tags: inequality, trigonometry, logarithms

### Problem

Prove that $$\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+n) < \sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{1}{6}\right) + ... + \sin\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right) < \frac{1}{2}\ln(n) + \ln(2)$$

where $n$ is a positive integer.

### My Process

∵ for all $x > 0$
$$\sin(x) < x$$
∴  $$\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{1}{6}\right) + ... + \sin\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right) < \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{6} + ... + \frac{1}{2n}$$

∵ The integral of $1/n$ is $\ln(n)$
$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{6} + ... + \frac{1}{2n} < \frac{1}{2}\ln(n)$$

But I have NO clues about how to prove the left side inequality.

Can people give me some suggestions?

With great appreciation!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Your inequality seems wrong. 

$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + .. \frac{1}{2n} < \frac{1}{2}.ln(n)$ 

pick n = 10, and it gives $1.46448<1.151292$.

This is because the left side of the equation is a decreasing function. So the integral remains smaller.

Answer (score 1):

*The right inequality:* As already noted in the comments, your proof of the right inequality needs to be fixed: We have (see for example [Bounds for the Harmonic k-th partial sum.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2832848/42969))
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \sin\left( \frac{1}{2k}\right) < \frac 12\sum_{k=1}^n  \frac 1k < \frac 12 \bigl(\ln(n) + 1 \bigr) < \frac 12 \ln(x) + \ln(2) \, .
$$

---

*The left inequality:* If we can show that
$$ \tag{$*$}
 \sin(x) > \frac 12 \ln (1+2x)
$$
for $0 < x < 1$ then
$$
 \sum_{k=1}^n \sin\left( \frac{1}{2k}\right)
> \frac 12 \sum_{k=1}^n   \ln \left( \frac{k+1}{k}\right)
= \frac 12 \ln (1+n)
$$
is the desired estimate.

In order to prove $(*)$ we consider the function
$$
 \sin(x) - \frac 12 \ln (1+2x)
$$
on the interval $[0, 1]$. We have $f(0) = 0$ and (using [Using mean value theorem to show that $\cos (x)>1-x^2/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/887954/42969))
$$
 f'(x) = \cos(x) - \frac{1}{1+2x} > 1 - \frac 12 x^2 - \frac{1}{1+2x} \\
 = \frac{x(4-x-2x^2)}{2(1+2x)} > 0
$$
for $0 < x < 1$, so that $f$ is strictly increasing, and $(*)$ follows.